# Disable buttons in background during Facebook popup (Corona)

Tags: facebook, popup, coronasdk

I am using inbuilt Facebook api in Corona to get a Facebook popup. However the pop up does not cover the full screen so buttons in background are visible and clickable. There is a home button. When I click on home button in the back ground the Facebook popup does not close and app returns to home screen in background. I would like either to return to homescreen with pop closed or to make home button not clickable if popup is open. 
If I disable the button in the background when Facebook popup appears there is no way to know the user closed the popup and so I can enable the button.
Is there a way to make Facebook popup full screen or to know that the popup was closed. ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the dialog is closed you SHOULD get an event of type "dialog" sent to your facebook listener that you supplied to facebook.login().  With this in  mind, you could disable all controls on the screen, show the dialog, and then whenever you get a dialog event restore control functionality.  The trick is to then maintain some relationship between your original listener and the code that pops the dialog.